# dotnet missing after update to .NET Core SDK 2.1.4

Tags: .net, cmd, .net-core

After .NET Core SDK updated to 2.1.4 on Windows Server 2016 `dotnet` command disappeared. CMD:

```
dotnet --info
'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check whether the `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk` folder exists on the server.

If it does not, you will need to (re)install it.
https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows#install

If the folder exists, type `echo %PATH%` at a command prompt and check whether `C:\Program Files\dotnet` appears within the output.

If it does not, you will need to add it:

`SETX /M PATH "%PATH%;c:\Program Files\dotnet"`

You should run `SETX` from a administrative command-prompt. Alternatively you can check the PATH variable (and edit it) using the Windows Advanced Settings dialog.

Comment: Setting this in a command window is volatile. Either use setx or change in the system advanced settings environment. Also your command will set variable `PATH ` with a trailing space.

Comment: @LotPings thank you for that - I did not know about `SETX` until now